# Override method inline in Swift?

Tags: java, swift, interface

In JAVA I can create an object uses an interface, and override the method, do in the same spot. How is it possible in Swift?

JAVA Interface:

```
public interface ImageListener {
    public void completed(Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

JAVA method call:

```
Utility.getImage(_id, "photo", new ImageListener() {
          public void completed(Bitmap bitmap){
         userSettingHolder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   }
});
```

Swift protocol:

```
public protocol ImageListener {

    func completed(image: UIImage?)
}
```

Swift method call? I tried something like this:

```
class MyImageListener : ImageListener {
        func completed(image: UIImage?) {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    Utility.getImage(item.id, attributeName: "image", completion: MyImageListener());
```

But get an irritating error:

[image]

Comment: I only used Swift once, like a year ago and it was okay back then however I encountered the same issue. I believe Swift doesn't have anonymous classes like you do in Java. Take a look at closures. They are anonymous blocks in Swift and probably will do the job.

Comment: @János that's not the way you do it in swift. Don't code in swift using "Java mentality" and nobody in swift community uses the word listener for observers, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use closures inline:

```
enum Utility {
    static func getImage(_ id: String, attributeName: String, completion: (_ image: UIImage) -> Void) {
        // get image here
        let image = UIImage()
        // pass image to handler
        completion(image)
    }
}

Utility.getImage("42", attributeName: "photo") { image in
    // your inline code with image processing
    print(image.description)
}
```